# Groovy map coercion produced <class>_groovyProxy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a java class which I'm trying to instantiate.

```
PackageGenerator gen = [
      fileName: "file.xml",
      platform: "windows",
      version: "1.0"]
println ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(gen);
```

produce:

```
PackageGenerator_groovyProxy[fileName=<null>, platform=<null>, version=<null>]
```

but if I write it with the `.with` way:

```
PackageGenerator gen = new PackageGenerator()
gen.with {
    fileName = "file.xml"
    platform = "windows"
    version = "1.0"
}
println ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(gen);
```

produces:

```
PackageGenerator[fileName="file.xml", platform="windows", version="1.0"]
```

what's causing the groovy proxy class to be used instead of the actual class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_groovyProxy` suffix is added when `Proxy` implementation is created if the original object is not assignable to the demanded type. I believe what is happening here is that

```
PackageGenerator gen = [
  fileName: "file.xml",
  platform: "windows",
  version: "1.0"]
```

is the same as

```
PackageGenerator gen = [
  fileName: "file.xml",
  platform: "windows",
  version: "1.0"] as PackageGenerator
```

and as a `Map` cannot be cast to `PackageGenerator` a proxy is generated.

You can easily overcome this by using a map constructor

```
PackageGenerator gen = new PackageGenerator(
  fileName: "file.xml",
  platform: "windows",
  version: "1.0")
```

which implementation is very close to what you have written in the second example